# Order a table to show items with a specific value in column A and then sort the rest by column B

Tags: mysql, eloquent

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
id | country_id | name
1  | 14         | Apple
2  | 85         | Microsoft
3  | 99         | Tesla
```

I want to sort the table to first show all the rows that have `country_id=85` and then all the other rows sorted by the `name` column.

So, in the example above, the output should be:

```
Microsoft
Apple
Tesla
```

Preferably this should be done with `Eloquent` (in `Laravel`) but a raw query will also do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In `MySQL` you can use:

```
select id,
       country_id,
       name
from test 
order by case 
             when country_id=85 then 1
             else name 
         end asc;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d78fcbaceadd37898aa3167db33e221c

Comment: Looks good, but I may have explained one detail poorly -  the stocks where country_id=85 should also be sorted by name among themselves. I'm looking at this syntax and it doesn't seem exactly possible.

Comment: @svetipetar like this : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5d7453f197fe79281248138a4e87be06